# Displaying a temporary message while loading a page - Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using Django admin and I'm looking for showing a message to user while my page is loading (something like: please wait...). Is there a way to show this temporary message if the user clicked `'admin:appname_modelname_changelist'` link (load an object to change). 
I'm not using ajax to transfer the request. 
I'm looking for something like *ajaxStart* and *ajaxComplete* functions in order to control start/end loading page.

Comment: why do you even need this? Admin tasks are supposed to finish quickly.

Comment: I'm doing some data handling in save_related() modelAdmin method that requires a lapse of time, I tested some javascript codes but it did not get when the page start and complete.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the admin template and add a Javascript onClick handler on the link to show a loader (with jQuery for example).

Overriding admin templates:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

jQuery onClick handler:
https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Thank for your reply, but i need something like *ajaxStart* and *ajaxComplete* ajax functions in order to control start/end loading page

Comment: Why do you want to control the completion? The user will be redirected after the request is finished so the loader will vanish anyway.